# svn diff -x (v1.6) does not accept my diff option --unified=40

Tags: shell, svn, diff, command-line-arguments, sh

I often use this command line that works great on Subversion 1.6.11 and GNU diff 2.8.1.

```
svn diff -x '--unified --ignore-space-change --ignore-all-space --ignore-eol-style --show-c-function' --no-diff-deleted my-file | vim -
```

However I want to increase the context lines using the `diff` option `--unified=40` but all my attempts fail:

```
$ svn diff -x '--unified=40' my-file
svn: Error parsing diff options: Missing parameter for the specified command line option

$ svn diff -x '--unified 40' my-file
svn: Invalid argument '40' in diff options

$ svn diff -x '--unified\=40' my-file
svn: Error parsing diff options: Bad character specified on command line

$ svn diff -x '-u 40' my-file
svn: Invalid argument '40' in diff options

$ svn diff -x '-u=40' my-file
svn: Error parsing diff options: Bad character specified on command line

$ svn diff -x '-U' my-file
svn: Error parsing diff options: Bad character specified on command line
```

I also want to ignore changes in comment lines using the `diff` option `--ignore-matching-lines='^[ \t]*#'` but same errors.

**Is there a workaround to this `svn diff -x` issue?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Subversion doesn't use GNU diff to generate the diff.  [It has it's own implementation of diff](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.examine.diff) (see the last paragraph of the section at the link).  The internal diff implementation only has a few options as you can see from the output of `svn help diff`:

> ```
> -x [--extensions] ARG    : Specify differencing options for external diff or
>                           internal diff or blame. Default: '-u'. Options are
>                           separated by spaces. Internal diff and blame take:
>                             -u, --unified: Show 3 lines of unified context
>                             -b, --ignore-space-change: Ignore changes in
>                               amount of white space
>                             -w, --ignore-all-space: Ignore all white space
>                             --ignore-eol-style: Ignore changes in EOL style
>                             -p, --show-c-function: Show C function name
> ```

You probably want to do `svn diff --diff-cmd=/usr/bin/diff -x '--unified=40' my-file` so that Subversion will choose the external diff too at `/usr/bin/diff` (or whatever path you want).

You can also configure Subversion to always use the external diff command through the configuration file.  There is a [section on using external diff and merge tools](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externaldifftools.html) in the [Subversion book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can write a small `shell script` that does this:

```
#!/bin/bash
diff --unified=40 <(svn cat "$1") "$1"
```

Comment: Hi Roch. Thanks for your answer. But please, could you add in your answer an example how to use the provided shell script (also give an example output). Cheers ;-)